# How to pass an array to an User Defined Aggregation Function in Spark (UDAF)

Tags: apache-spark

I'd like to pass an Array as input schema in an UDAF.

The example I give is pretty simple, it just sums 2 vectors. Actually my use case is more complexe and I need to use an UDAF.

```
import sc.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Array(10.2, 12.3, 11.2)),
  (1, Array(11.2, 12.6, 10.8)),
  (2, Array(12.1, 11.2, 10.1)),
  (2, Array(10.1, 16.0, 9.3)) 
  ).toDF("siteId", "bidRevenue")


class BidAggregatorBySiteId() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("bidRevenue", ArrayType(DoubleType))))

  def bufferSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("sumArray", ArrayType(DoubleType))))

  def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(DoubleType)

  def deterministic = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
      buffer.update(0, Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
      }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
      val seqBuffer = buffer(0).asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[Double]]
      val seqInput = input(0).asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[Double]]
      buffer(0) = seqBuffer.zip(seqInput).map{ case (x, y) => x + y }
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
     val seqBuffer1 = buffer1(0).asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[Double]]
     val seqBuffer2 = buffer2(0).asInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[Double]]
     buffer1(0) = seqBuffer1.zip(seqBuffer2).map{ case (x, y) => x + y }
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = { 
    buffer
  }
}
val fun = new BidAggregatorBySiteId()

df.select($"siteId", $"bidRevenue" cast(ArrayType(DoubleType)))
.groupBy("siteId").agg(fun($"bidRevenue"))
.show
```

All works fine for transformations before the "show" action. But the show raises the error:

> scala.MatchError: [WrappedArray(21.4, 24.9, 22.0)] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.InputAggregationBuffer)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:160)

The structure of my dataframe is :

```
root
 |-- siteId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bidRevenue: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

> df.dtypes =  Array[(String, String)] = Array(("siteId", "IntegerType"), ("bidRevenue", "ArrayType(DoubleType,true)"))

Tanks for you valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any
```

Above method is called once a group is processed completely to get the final result.
As you are initializing and updating only buffer's 0th index

```
i.e. buffer(0)
```

So you need to return the 0th index value at the end as your aggregated results are stored at 0 index.

```
  def evaluate(buffer: Row) = {
    buffer.get(0)
  }
```

Above modification to evaluate() method will result in:

```
// +------+---------------------------------+
// |siteId|bidaggregatorbysiteid(bidRevenue)|
// +------+---------------------------------+
// |     1|               [21.4, 24.9, 22.0]|
// |     2|               [22.2, 27.2, 19.4]|
// +------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't see the obvious and you did.

Comment: @FrançoisBagaïni No problem, It would be great if you could up vote the answer or mark it as solution.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote the answer, because I haven't enough reputation